# MongoDB insert/update/delete elements of an array which is an element to another array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, crud

Consider the following document:

```
{
    "entity_id" : 10,
    "features" : 
    [ 
    {
        "10" : "Test System 2"
    }, 
    {
        "20" : "System 2 Description"
    }, 
    {
        "30" : ["Free", "Monthly", "Quaterly"]
    }, 
    {
        "40" : ["Day", "Swing"]
    }
],
}
```

I need to, in as few statements as possible, to achieve the following:

1. Given a document like so:

   ```
   {"feature_id" : "30", "value" : ["Free"]}
   ```

   get the corresponding element of the array "features" to contain ["Free"] instead of ["Free", "Monthly", "Quaterly"]
2. Given a document like so:

   ```
   {"feature_id" : "50", "value" : ["Bonds", "Commodities"]}
   ```

   create a new element of the array "features" looking like

   ```
   {"50" : ["Bonds", "Commodities"]}
   ```
3. Given a document like so:

   ```
   {"feature_id" : "40", "value" : ""}
   ```

remove the corresponding element from the array "features".

Comment: So, what was your question?

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you just need to work with standard [array update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/). 1) [`$` update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), 2) [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/), 3) [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

Comment: @Stennie I tried a lot of different approaches, mostly involving $update and $push (not familiar with $pull), too numerous to post here. Obviously none worked...

Comment: I think the issue is be that you've mixed your notion of arrays and embedded objects. Will comment with suggested data model.

Comment: @Alex: in general it is best to include code examples of what you've actually tried, as this can help narrow the problem. Sometimes it can just be a small adjustment in syntax from what you already have :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Data model

Your data model isn't easy to work with given your desired updates.

If you want to use an array, I would suggest changing the document structure to look like:

```
{
    "entity_id" : 10,
    "features" : [
        {
            feature_id: "10",
            value : "Test System 2"
        },
        {
            feature_id: "20",
            value: "System 2 Description"
        }, 
        {
            feature_id: "30",
            value: ["Free", "Monthly", "Quaterly"]
        }, 
        {
            feature_id: "40",
            value: ["Day", "Swing"]
        }
    ],
}
```

Alternatively, you could model as an embedded document:

```
{
    "entity_id" : 10,
    "features" : {
        "10" : "Test System 2",
        "20" : "System 2 Description",
        "30" : ["Free", "Monthly", "Quaterly"],
        "40" : ["Day", "Swing"]
    }
}
```

The benefit of modeling as an array is that you can add a [multikey index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents) across all features/values.

If you model as an embedded document, you could reference fields directly (i.e. `features.10`). This assumes you know what the keys are going to be, and you would have to index each feature value separately.

I'll assume the first format for the examples below. Also note that your key values have to match in type (so string `"10"` will not match number `10`).

#### Example 1

> Given a document like so:
>
> {"feature_id" : "30", "value" : ["Free"]}
>   get the corresponding element of the array "features" to contain ["Free"] instead of ["Free", "Monthly", "Quaterly"]

Sample update:

```
db.docs.update(
    // Criteria (assumes entity_id is unique)
    {
        entity_id: 10,
        features: {
            // Using $elemMatch to find feature_id with string "30"
            $elemMatch: { feature_id: "30" },
        }
    },

    // Update
    { $set: {
        "features.$.value" : ["Free"]
    }}
)
```

#### Example 2

> Given a document like so:
>
> {"feature_id" : "50", "value" : ["Bonds", "Commodities"]}
>   create a new element of the array "features" looking like
>
> {"50" : ["Bonds", "Commodities"]}

Sample update:

```
db.docs.update(
    // Criteria (assumes entity_id is unique)
    {
        entity_id: 10,
    },

    // Update
    { $push: {
        "features" : { "feature_id" : "50", value: ["Bonds", "Commodities"] }
    }}
)
```

#### Example 3

> Given a document like so:
>
> {"feature_id" : "40", "value" : ""}
>
> remove the corresponding element from the array "features".

Sample update:

```
db.docs.update(
    // Criteria (assumes entity_id is unique)
    {
        entity_id: 10,
    },

    // Update
    { $pull: {
        "features" : { "feature_id" : "40" }
    }}
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I don't know at this point if changing the structure feasible, or even possible. Coming from the SQL world, it feels very uncomfy to have literals ("feature_id", "value") repeated in every "row" just because the environment is not conducive to specifying simple CRUD operations.

Comment: @Alex: if you have a known set of feature keys and you only want to index a subset of features, you may prefer the second suggested data model with the embedded document. With an embedded document CRUD operations for fields can use [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/). CRUD operations on arrays are necessarily different because you need to specify how to find the value in the array by providing either an array index or query criteria.

Comment: The second suggested data model is exactly what I have currently and what gives me a hard time to pick up the correct syntax.

Comment: @Alex: the second data model is not exactly what you have currently included in your description: you have an *array* of embedded documents, rather than a single embedded document.

Comment: Oops! You're certainly correct, my bad.
So, my model is, in your view, completely unsuitable for the update operations in the "normal" sense?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, not suited for the update operations that you want to perform on individual fields in the array/embedded documents.